# Working with Multiple Windows

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

In my MainMenu.xib, I have the main window of my app with web view, Now i have added a new window (with text field and button) in MainMenu.xib.

I have problem to add a menu tab where i click and my newly added window appears (Not on app Launching). How to connect menu tab item with window..???

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should use either viewcontroller or navigationController. And you can add your button on `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: I see this question is for OSX ?

Comment: Do you like with binding or should I show using codes?

Comment: Using codes also will be interesting. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to do it without a single line of code?

i.e. **Using Binding**.

Here we go:

Create a secondary Window that you want to open on menu click.

Uncheck "Release when Close"

[image]

Create a new menu item : <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+drag from menu to window, select "makeKeyAndOrderFront"

That's it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now when i click on option from menu it shows me newly added window but does not loading web view which was working before when i wan running application...???:-(

Comment: Try will creating separate object Controller for secondary window